# C# HTML editor to create forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I posted a similar topic for RoR, but didn't know how to edit my tags, so I'm making a new one for C#...
I'm looking for a **HTML editor which can be integrated in a C# app** that has the possibility to create forms.
Not forms per se, but I need the possibility to add radiobuttons, input fields, checkboxes and so on.
There are many editors that provide Richt text (bold, italic, indentation and so on) but what I need goes a bit further, so help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm really confused.  Are you describing Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I meant somethins as seen below. A component to add to a windows form. Sorry if I wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: Are you looking for a drag-and-drop WYSIWYG experience, or just allow the user to define fields, radio button option sets, checkbox sets, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visual Studio Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/)  these are freely provided by microsoft as the lightweight versions of Visual Studio, you can get the edition in whichever language you prefer.

Keep in mind though, in about exactly a month, the 2010 versions will be coming out with a lot of improvements, including big ones on the html side of things so keep an eye out to update then if you go this route.

If you mean an editor like this to plug into an existing application...then I've totally missed your point and you should ignore this :)